# Why is Minimize spinning?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

The command

```
Minimize[a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + a*b + b*c + a*c - 
(a + b - c)*Sqrt[2 a*b + b*c + a*c] - (b + c - a)* Sqrt[2 b*c + b*a + a*c] -
(a + c - b)*Sqrt[2 a*c + a*b + b*c], a >= 0 && b >= 0 && c >= 0, {a, b, c}]
```

is executing on my comp without any output during more than an hour. The expected result is

> 0, { a-> c, b -> c}

or something similar. 
How to obtain it?  I am  interested only in a symbolic result, not in a numeric one.

Addition. Even the command

```
Minimize[(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + a*b + b*c + 
a*c - (a + b - c)*Sqrt[2 a*b + b*c + a*c] - (b + c - a)*
 Sqrt[2 b*c + b*a + a*c] - (a + c - b)*
 Sqrt[2 a*c + a*b + b*c]) /. c -> 1, a >= 0 && b >= 0, {a, b}]
```

is spinning too.

Comment: The problem is that `Sqrt` isn't a function with a unique answer -- it can have two possible answers (plus or minus). Even in a very simple case, Mathematica cannot simplify. For instance `Sqrt[c^2]//FullSimplify` does not simplify to `c`.

Comment: You could simplify it perhaps, by setting `c -> 1`, since the function is homogeneous.  It's still equivalent to a degree 16 polynomial, so finding the critical points still seems to be time-consuming.  But at least the new problem is parameter-free, which should make it much faster.